# Getting error with GraphQL model in NestJS, using code-first approach

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I'm using the code-first approach in NestJS to create GraphQL schemas. I have the following definition. **Person** can have a **Dog**.

```
@ObjectType()
export class Person {
  @Field()
  name: string;
  @Field(type => Dog, { nullable: true })
  dog?: Dog;
}

@ObjectType()
export class Dog {
  @Field()
  breed: string
  @Field()
  name: string
}
```

When server starts up I get the following error message.

**ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Dog' before initialization**

What am I doing wrong? Does Dog need to be resolved by **@ResolveField()** in the resolver? In my case it's just a nested object within Person. Dog doesn't come from another service call.

Essentially, I want to represent the following structure.

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  dog?: {
    breed: string;
    name: string
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to do is declare `Dog` first:

```typescript
@ObjectType()
export class Dog {
  @Field()
  breed: string;
  @Field()
  name: string;
}

@ObjectType()
export class Person {
  @Field()
  name: string;
  @Field(type => Dog, { nullable: true })
  dog?: Dog;
}
```

Comment: OMG... I cannot believe it was a simple as that. Huge thanks!!